# how to run a batch file using c++?

Tags: c++

how to run a batch file using c++?

I dont know any thing about that

Comment: On windows? Is it a Win32 app, a .Net app? A vanilla console app? All these things (and more) affect the best place to start. Do you want to run the bat file as part of the build? Or as part of your finished, running app?

Comment: system ("C:\\batc.bat"), my batch file(batc.bat) is in the C directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the system() function.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/

Comment: My scenario is I have to run a .bat file which is in another folder?

what is Syntax for that if u can tell please?

Comment: how can i give the path of .bat file in your program